# Connect Microsoft Access Database in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, jdbc

My platform is Windows 7 64 bit with Eclipse Juno, my code is quite simple,

```
 public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=student.mdb","","");
       //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student.mdb");

        System.out.println("Row is added");
        }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("does not added:"+e);
     }
}
```

}

I put the student.mdb file under the directory of the project, and when I run the program, the compiler showes:
does not added:java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data sour
ce name not found and no default driver specified

Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

BTW, I have already installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe on my computer.

Comment: First, do you have Access 64-bit installed?

Comment: Hi Elliott, I didn't have 64-bit Access, only Access 2010 32-bit...

Comment: AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe But, is it okay if I install this?

Comment: Hi, Gord, I think you are right, the problems are similar. Sorry for the duplication :(